# Where do we really need to use wide character stream wcout?

Tags: c++

I can't get the point of using `std::wcout`. As far as I've understood the `wide stream` object corresponds to a  C wide-oriented stream (`ISO C 7.19.2/5`). When do we really need to use it in practice. I'm pretty sure it doesn't suit to output a character from an implementation's `wide character set` `N3797::3.9.1/5 [basic.fundamental]`, because

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
    std::locale loc = std::locale ("en_US.UTF-8");
    std::wcout.imbue(loc);
    std::cout << "ي" << std::endl;                         // OK!
    std::wcout << "ي" << std::endl;                        // Empty string
    std::wcout << "L specifier = " << L"ي" << std::endl;   // J
    std::wcout << "u specifier = " << u"ي" << std::endl;   // 0x400,eac
    std::wcout << "u8 specifier = " << u8"ي" << std::endl; // empty string
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c117c0254e7d388)**

We can see that `wcout`'s `operator<<` didn't print these characters correct, meanwhile `cout`'s `operator<<` does it well. I've also chech `wcout` on any other charater like 
`'л', 'ਚੰ', 'ਗਾ', 'კ', 'ა', 'რ', 'გ', 'ი'` and so on and so forth, but it prints well only a Latinic characters or a numbers.

Comment: FWIW, libc++ correctly prints `wcout << L"ي"`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f56246a48ab2361d

Comment: IIRC, streams do not (yet) support the Unicode character types `char16_t` and `char32_t`. Therefore, they'll probably use the `void*` address output instead of string output.

Comment: @dyp But `ostream cout` prints it correctly. May you mean _wide_ streams? If so, it seems strange, because I thought wide streams are introduced to use they along with `whcar_t`, `char16_t` and `char32_t`. Why not?

Comment: @dyp How could it ever depends on the library we're using? The terminal takes over the character printing.

Comment: *"But `ostream cout` prints it correctly"* What are you referring to? [`cout << u"hello world"`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1eb148af6d0ab76d) does not work as expected.

Comment: *"How could it ever depends on the library we're using?"* The library could contain bugs ;) I'm not sure if this is one, but different behaviour in two implementations is typically either UB/IB or a bug.

Comment: @dyp So `std::wcout << L"ي"` and `std::wcout << L'ي'` _must_ print exactly the same, right?

Comment: Well setting the locale to UTF-8 kind of defeats the point I think. It appears to me that wide-streams and wide-strings are used to deal with platforms that only want/can deal with fixed-width encodings like UCS-1, UTF-32 or similar.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv If `ي`, in whatever value the compiler translates the encoding of the source file to, is in the execution wide-character set, then yes, I think `wcout << L"ي"` and `wcout << L'ي'` must print the same text. -- edit: The locale probably also has some influence on that. If the character is not valid in the current locale, I bet there are no guarantees.

Comment: @dyp Thank you. But I've one more question: How can we look at the most extended character set? Can we print it into the terminal?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv I have no idea if there is a portable way. `wchar_t` is supposed to be able to represent all characters "in the current locale" (C Standard), but under Windows, it's a UTF-16 code unit. I'm not even sure if all values which `char` or `wchar_t` can represent are valid in all locales. But anyway, I'm skating on thin ice here. My knowledge of streams and locales is rather superficial.